# Unable to convert partial VLAN from systemd to netplan

Tags: networking, netplan

I will start by saying I do not know whether I am dealing with a user (me!) error (me!), a netplan bug, or even a systemd bug. I won't bloat this question with configurations and diagnostics yet, just in case someone tells me I have missed something obvious.

I have a network that I am slowly and cautiously upgrading to 802.1Q VLAN. I have basically four VLANs, but three are tagged exclusively by my Netgear prosafe switches at the moment. The fourth VLAN is running with my ubuntu server firewall (shorewall), which is also my core router, defining a VLAN interface via systemd-networkd. My two wifi access points (unifi) also tag the traffic for clients themselves. This all works the way I would expect, including my isc-dhcp-server leasing ip4 addresses to clients connecting to this guest SSID, subnet and VLAN.

This core router has three files associated with the real ethernet interface in /etc/systemd/network/. The first is a netdev to define the VLAN virtual interface, the second is a network file that defines the underlying ethernet interface and assigns it three static ip4 and three static ip6 subnetworks (addresses and routes), as well as associating the VLAN with itself. The third is another network file that assigns a single ip4 and single ip6 address for the VLAN interface.

As I said, I haven't seen anything that suggests this is an illegal combination and all my testing confirms that it works as intended. The "real" interface has six addresses, and the VLAN interface has its own addresses that DO NOT OVERLAP with the six subnets of the "real" interface.

I've spent ages looking at netplan examples, but can't see anything similar. Basically, my best effort resulted in traffic mayhem because the VLAN interface inherited ALL the addresses and routes of the real interface, as well as its own!

I gave up and reverted to systemd on my core router and tried to work on a simplified netplan configuration for a development system (ubuntu server 18.04.1 with netplan.io version 0.40.1~18.04.2).

With one "real" and one VLAN interface, each with a single ip4 and ip6 static address. My best effort (in a single yaml) yields identical ip4 and ip6 addresses for both interfaces, while the ip4 and ip6 of the VLAN interface are nowhere to be seen. This configuration is non-functional - traffic can't get in and out successfully.

So, to ask a simple question: am I trying to do something that netplan OUGHT to support? (i.e. addresses/routes assigned to the physical ethernet interface and different addresses/routes assigned to the VLAN interface?)

If someone can give me a simple answer (that I can understand!!), I'll either fix it myself, or ask for help and provide more detailed information.

Thanks in anticipation...

Comment: For further assistance, please attach your netplan.yaml, the output of your routing table, and a description of what part of the routing table is not what you expect.

Comment: I have set up the configuration with systemd-networkd and tested that traffic flows as I expect, on both the base interface and the VLAN. I thought it would be useful to report this first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, netplan should support addresses both on the ethernet interface and on a vlan attached to that interface.

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies! This is excellent news. I am much happier knowing that I am trying to do something which ought to be possible.I will set up a systemd-networkd definition on my test server and show you the "correct" address/routes, then add the yaml and the "wrong" address/routes for comparison. Don't think I am rude if it takes a day or so to do - we have house guests all weekend and my wife says they get priority!

Comment: Having to put files elsewhere is a bit boring, but here is my working systemd network configuration:

https://pastebin.com/J1rzScCE

Comment: ... and here is a collection of my systemd network definitions which created the configuration above.

https://pastebin.com/Wta6N3md

Comment: Here is my best-efforts netplan definition to create the desired network definition:

https://pastebin.com/dfWnsUmQ

Comment: ... and finally, the network configuration that netplan created:

https://pastebin.com/hvg1XqvB

Comment: I see it creates the expected VLAN virtual interface, although with a slightly different interface name to that created by systemd. Also, the ip4 and ip6 addresses for the real interface are correct. However, the virtual interface has been assigned the identical ip4 and ip6 addresses of the real interface. Not surprisingly, the routing is all wrong. I lose all ability to ssh into the machine, but fortunately I can reconfigure it again from the system console.

Comment: I tried to modify the yaml a bit here to get something closer to your working systemd configs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FX8Fs6ycGr/

But it's odd, and a little hard to make the sure values are okay because I can't distinguish your "good" ip addr output from the "bad" one. I also have a setup on a server on my own, where the addresses are correctly being applied to the interfaces. Could you share the config generated by netplan for systemd (that's in /run/systemd/network)?

Comment: Firstly, I apologise for not noticing your very helpful reply earlier, Mathieu. Happy New Year!

Comparing yamls:

1. The ip6 address is NOT a /60. Its my delegated prefix "owned" by my gateway router. The test host is in a /80 subnet. Anyway, I thought ALL ip6 interface addresses must be /64 even if not, although that statement always had me very confused and uncertain.
2. The gateway4 and gateway6 lines are interesting, although shouldn't they have masks associated with them?
3. My route clauses seem to do the same thing, although I can see I somehow forgot to code a default ip4 route.

Comment: OK. My 2nd test netplan still went wrong the same way. `/run/systemd/network` files are at [https://pastebin.com/V0Rb911x], and the `ip shows` at [https://pastebin.com/jUetAagC]. I wonder whether my filenames are confusing netplan because they all start with "10-"? Unfortunately, I will be away next week and can't do a test without losing contact with the test server.